# Why can't I show content of my WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

My problem is that the content of the tables can't be shown on my browser. when I type

```
http://localhost:61306/MyWcfDataService.svc
```

the tables are shown but I when I want to access to the content of a table and type

```
http://localhost:18024/WcfDataService1.svc/Item
```

I got [image: THIS ERROR]

Thanks in advance

**Update**

Error Detail :

[image]

Comment: In IE go to Tools->Internet Options, select the Advanced tab and uncheck "Show friendly HTTP error messages". When you do that you should see more details which can give you some hints about what's happening. Alternatively setup Fiddler and you should be able to trace all the traffic and should see what's happening.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using IE I would recommend disabling friendly HTTP error messages to see the actual response from the server - go to Tools->Internet Options, select the Advanced tab and uncheck "Show friendly HTTP error messages". Then, take a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx) post which shows how to turn on more detailed diagnostic information.